# DataTables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unique' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with my jquery datatables code. This new error just popped out of nowhere.

I have a suspicion it might be because of all the library files I'm loading, the datatable initialization is failing as the datatable files have somehow not loaded in time because this error seems to pop up right after I added the extra libraries and most of the forums for similar questions seem to suggest that.

However my error has not been resolved. The order in which the datatable libraries are loaded should be fine as they were working perfectly before.

This is how I'm loading my script files:

```
<script src="../assets/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/app.min.js"></script>

<!-- Libs-->
<script src="../assets/libs/flatpickr/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/libs/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/libs/jquery-toast/jquery.toast.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/libs/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/libs/dropify/dropify.min.js"></script>

<!-- third party js -->
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/vendor/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
```

This is my datatable initialization:

```
var table = $("#ltable").DataTable({
    select: {
        style: "single"
    },
    columnDefs: [
    {
        "targets": [ 0 ],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
    },
    {
        "targets": [ 1 ],
        "visible": false
    }],
    rowCallback: function( row, data ) {
        switch(data[1]) {
        case "":
        $(row).css('background-color','#f1f3fa');
        break;
        case "Open":
        $(row).css('background-color','#fbffc5');
        break;
        case "Closed":
        $(row).css('background-color','#ceffc5');
        break;
        case "Denied":
        $(row).css('background-color','#ffdac5');
        break;
    }},
    language: {
        search: "",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search",
        scrollX: true,
        sLengthMenu: "_MENU_items",
        paginate: {
            previous: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-left'>",
            next: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-right'>"
        }
    },
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50,100, -1], [10, 25, 50,100, "All"]],
    deferRender: true,
    drawCallback: function() {
        $(".dataTables_paginate > .pagination").addClass("pagination-rounded")
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Jojo Thomas, have you tried initializing your datatable with minimal configuration? like a simple `var table = $("#ltable").DataTable();`,  then incremeting with one configuration at time, in order to discover where the error pops up?

Comment: not really, because all of this config was working perfectly for ages and seemed to stop suddenly but I'll try

Comment: nope, even a simple bare init is showing the same error

Comment: have you updated any library or script that is being loaded? Updates may cause dependency problems

Comment: no, all the datatable libraries I'm loading (marked as third-party js) above have been the same. The only new libraries I'm loading are the ones marked Libs and even after I removed them, the datatable error continues to persist. All of these are local libraries, no CDNs so remote updates are also impossible.

Comment: ok, I think we will need an working sample of your code, can you provide it to us?

Answer (score 1):

In my case columns defined while building the  datatable were not in sync with columns given in the html. Like I had  removed some columns from data table, but forgot to change colspan property in html (reducing 3 to 2). After I corrected, and kept both html columns and datatable columns in sync, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now. Someone had changed the code on one of the API's which populated the datatable which led to an un-handled error response consequently leading to an error in the datatable initialization.

However since there was no earlier support or answers both on Stackoverflow and Datatable's official forum, for future reference, it is an initialization error that is caused due to either one of 2 reasons -:

1. Your libraries are not loaded properly. Check the specific ones and their order. Use the Datatable library config download [builder](https://datatables.net/download/).
2. The markup that is being used for the datatable is incorrect for some reason so always good to check what is actually being rendered in case of dynamic data.